# What permission is need for one to use the type parameter in the Facebook Graph Api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I used read_stream, publish_stream and manage_pages as the permissions for the facebook graph api so that i can access and manipulate a user's feed. I tried using the type parameter to filter the feed and return posts that have messages i.e. by adding 'type=message' to the url but this does not seem to work.

I have tried using the sample in facebook developers' page and it work there. I then compared the two urls (one from the facebook developers' page and the other from my web app) but the only difference was they had different access_tokens. Thus, i concluded that the problem might be the permissions so i am wondering what permission will allow me to perform this operation.

Answer (score 1):

When you said 'Sample in Facebook Developers' page were you referring to the [Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)?

If so, the explorer automatically requests metadata on queries by silently adding a '?metadata=1' to the query.

If you need the metadata, you should add this too, bearing in mind that there's a namespace collision between the properties of some objects and the metadata (i.e some objects have a field named 'type' which is suppressed if you force the metadata to be returned - you get the 'type' field from the metadata instead)